# FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules. Error in APK build react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

I have built my app using `gradlew assembleRelease`. On dev environment I have no errors. But I install APK on my phone my application crashes. I have used `./adb logcat` to find some errors and got this:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules`

`com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: n is not a function. (In 'n(u&&u[0])', 'n' is "1")`

What can be wrong with my build? I can not get logs using flipper:((